# mostrar datos de mi función en php en una tabla html

Tags: php, array, json, jsonarray

tengo la siguiente función que me trae productos de mi base de datos pero valida que si el código está repetido solo sume las cantidades al código existente, ya lo hace bien , solo que me surgen dos dudas.

```
$entradas = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$entradas[] = $row['ProductosRechazados'];
}                                                          

function procesarEntradas($entradas, $base = 'codigo', $acumular = 'cantidad') {
        // Array para acumular
        $totales = [];
                                   
        // Iterando elementos de entrada
        foreach ($entradas as $entrada) {
        // Parseando elementos por cada entrada
        $items =json_decode($entrada, true);
                               
        // Iterando sobre items de cada entrada
        foreach($items as $item) {
        // Primer asignación, omitir suma posterior en caso de...
        if (!isset($totales[$item[$base]])) {
          $totales[$item[$base]] = $item;
          continue;
          }
                                           
        // Acumular valores encontrados
        $totales[$item[$base]][$acumular] += $item[$acumular];
        }
}
                                   
return json_encode(array_values($totales));
                                   
}
                               
print_r(procesarEntradas($entradas));
```

esto es lo que esta dentro de mi **$entradas[]:**  `Array ( [0] => [{"id": "560", "codigo": "1005", "cantidad": "30", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW MATE 20 LITE NE"}, {"id": "559", "codigo": "1004", "cantidad": "30", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO XIA"}] [1] => [{"id": "560", "codigo": "1005", "cantidad": "30", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW MATE 20 LITE NE"}, {"id": "559", "codigo": "1004", "cantidad": "30", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO XIA"}] [2] => [{"id": "9109", "codigo": "1004", "cantidad": "10", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 NE"}, {"id": "9110", "codigo": "1005", "cantidad": "10", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ"}] )`

**Primera :** el resultado que me arroja está bien solo que la letra ñ la pasa así **DISE\u00d1O** debería ser **DISEÑO** cosa que me extraña ya que en donde establezco o configuro mi conexión a la base de datos tengo agrado el 'utf8' (ya que como muestro que dentro de **$entradas[]:** si aparece la letra ñ )  se perderá en el proceso de mi función o algo ?.

**Segunda :** quiero meter la función que les muestro en una tabla HTML para darle presentación a la información de tal manera que esperaría que quedara así :

```
$Codigos_result=procesarEntradas($entradas);           
                          
foreach ($Codigos_result as $code){

 echo "<tr>";
                                
 echo "<td>" . $code['id'] . "</td>";
    
 echo "<td>" . $code["codigo"] . "</td>";
    
 echo "<td>" . $code["descripcion"] . "</td>";

 echo "<td>" . $code["cantidad"] . "</td>";
    
 echo "</tr> ";
}
```

y esto que sigue es lo que arroja mi `print_r(procesarEntradas($entradas));`   [{"id":"560","codigo":"1005","cantidad":70,"descripcion":"3 EN 1 HW MATE 20 LITE NE"},{"id":"559","codigo":"1004","cantidad":70,"descripcion":"3 EN 1 DISE\u00d1O XIA"}]

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de establecer la conexion con la base de datos puedes establecer el formato UTF-8 de la siguiente manera:

```
$connection = new mysql('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database', '3306', '/path/to/socket', 'utf8');
```

De esta forma, todos los datos que se recuperen de la base de datos se devolverán en formato UTF-8, lo que evitará problemas al mostrar caracteres especiales como la ñ.

O puedes utilizar la función utf8_encode() de PHP para codificar el registro que contiene el caracter ñ en formato UTF-8

```
$registro = utf8_encode($registro);
```

Comment: el 'utf8' si lo tengo en mi conexión con la base de datos, porque cuando me traigo mi array en entradas[] si aparece bien escrita la pablara DISEÑO , pero luego las uso en mi función por laguna razón la decodifica mal ?

Comment: @Adiel y en el HTML tiene el <meta charset="UTF-8">??